# PPA dput Config error: missing FQDN set

Tags: ppa, launchpad, dput

I am trying to upload my PPA files using this page:
https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading
However, when I try to execute `dput ppa:your-lp-id/ppa <source.changes>` in my Terminal, I get the error `Config error: [PPA name] must have a fqdn set`.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like neither your `/etc/dput.cf` nor `~/.dput.cf` has a properly-configured `[ppa]` section.  It's not quite clear why since the stock configuration in both Debian and Ubuntu has it.  However, you should be able to work around this by adding the following to `~/.dput.cf`:

```
[ppa]
fqdn                    = ppa.launchpad.net
method                  = ftp
incoming                = ~%(ppa)s
login                   = anonymous
```

Comment: Something changed, still got an error. This time that gpg can't find a signature. I tried to rebuild the source package but the passphrase is incorrect, even though I just changed it. Once I figured that out, I will notify you :)